# special weblogic/java 8/webstart issue

Tags: java-8, weblogic, java-web-start

We need help in a special weblogic/java 8/webstart problem:

We are using Java 8 and weblogic server 12.1.3. We try to connect via Java webstart client with ssl (tslv1.2) to weblogic server but this doesn't work. If we're connecting whithout ssl the application is able to connect.

As long as we have been using Java 7 and weblogic server 12.1.1 it has been working.

We have a special situation as we're using a self signed certificate included in a *.jks file which we have stored in a jar-file. We are using a starter class to extract the *.jks file into a temp-dir to put it into the classpath (that has been the only way until Java 7 how it worked). We've set all ssl parameters as System.properties.

We've got only a connection error without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable debugging when starting the application

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake
```

You can also run wireshark to see what is going on more clearly.